.net core JWT-bearer authentication doesn't respect Cache-Control header
In .net core application I'm using JWT-bearer authentication to validate tokens received from Okta identity provider.
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var oktaOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection(Constants.ConfigSection.Okta).Get<OktaOptions>().Validate();

        var issuer = string.Format(oktaOptions.Issuer, oktaOptions.Domain);
        var metadataAddress = string.Format(oktaOptions.MetadataAddress, issuer);

        var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
            metadataAddress,
            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
            new HttpDocumentRetriever());

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = issuer,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKeyResolverUsingConfiguration = (_, _, _, _, configuration) => configuration.SigningKeys,
            ConfigurationManager = configurationManager,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = oktaOptions.Audience,
            // Allow for some drift in server time
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
        };
    });

It seems that ConfigurationManager doesn't respect Cache-Control header and always caches signing keys regardless of no-cache header value set by Okta when signing keys are about to change. Such behaviour will cause problems because old signing keys will be used to validate JWT tokens after new keys are issued. Are there any solutions to this problem?
